# $P(X≥x)$ for a geometric variable $X$?

Tags: probability, distributions, geometric-distribution

It can be shown that for a geometric variable $X$:

$P(X>x)=(1-p)^x$

But what about

$P(X≥x)$

---

Here http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/GeometricF.pdf
It's claimed that:

$P(X≥x)=(1-p)^x$

Answer (score 3):

I guess $P(X\ge x) = P(X>x-1)=(1-p)^{(x-1)}$, if $P(X>x)=(1-p)^{x}$, for discrete distribution.

Comment: Where do you get the $P(X > x-1)$?

Comment: Because you are calculating $P(X \ge x)$, which is equal to $P(X > x-1)$.

Comment: http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/GeometricF.pdf doesn't claim $P(X\ge x) = (1-p)^{x}$

Comment: @FrankFan Doesn't it? 'The probability that X is greater than or equal to x is...' ...?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the link uses $x = 0, 1, 2, ...$ while you probably use $x = 1, 2, ...$

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution):

[image]